# What is the difference between python string concatenation and string insertion

Tags: python

I want to know what is the diff between two string operations in python

```
filestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
database = "mysql";
```

Between this

```
filename = "/home/vmware/%s-%s.sql" % (database, filestamp)
```

and

```
filename = "/home/vmware/"+database+"-"+filestamp+".sql"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation using the '%' operators take the types of the interpolated values into account. String concatentation using the '+' will only work for strings. So you can't mix strings with numbers using the '+' operator. In general: string interpolation is what you want - at least for building strings from other values especially if you deal with different types.

Comment: If i use "+" am i committing any blunder , will my script work as expected . may be not efficent but will that cause any misfunctioning at any stage

Comment: @Mahakaal: `"a" + 1` gives `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`. `class C(object): pass`, `"a" + C()` gives `TypeError: Can't convert 'C' object to str implicitly`. However, some classes may define a `__radd__` method that's basically `return str(self) + some_str`.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach creates 1 string where as the second creates temporary strings which is wasted. Strings in python are immutable, once created you cannot modify it.

Comment: i don't understand "wasted" . i mean i am using in my program and they are working. whats problem in second. i am doing database backups in loop and its working. Under which case i can be in problem if i use second case

Comment: @Mahakaal: By wasted, I mean the temporary variables created between each concatenate operation is passed to the next and discarded. Each '+' creates a string variable that is used in the next (left to right) and discarded as it is no longer referred to. It works but not efficient.

Comment: It's confusing to talk about "variables" here. There are "anonymous" string objects being created in between.